# Как передать из одной функции в другую boolean значение?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть 3 функции которые слушают input'ы.value в форме сравнивая с паттернами.
В каждой из этих 3 функций условия:
Если переменная типа "boolean" равняется true тогда выполняем одни условия.
Если переменная типа "boolean" равняется false тогда выполняем другие условия.
Пример одна из 3 функций:

```js
var IsFormPhone = document.getElementById("form-phone");
IsFormPhone.onblur = function() {
    var Forma_Phone = IsFormPhone.value; // Получаем введёное значение input.value и присваиваем его.
    var answer_Phone = validation.isPhoneNumber(Forma_Phone); // Проверяется на валидацию.
    if (answer_Phone) { // Переменная которая выдаёт "boolean" значение после валидации.
        IsFormPhone.classList.remove('invalid');
        IsFormPhone.classList.add('valid');
    } else {
        IsFormPhone.classList.remove('valid');
        IsFormPhone.classList.add('invalid');
    };
};
```

Я хочу создать 4 функцию которая будет слушать эти 3 функции, принимая "boolean" значения от переменной "answer_Phone" и других двух "answer_Email", "answer_Name".
В этой новой 4 функции будут условия:
Если все три полученные значения "boolean" будут true тогда выполнится одно условие и наоборот.

Напишите пожалуйста как мне передавать из этих 3 функций "boolean" значения в эту 4 функцию.
И как 4 функции слушать эти 3 функции?
Например каждая из тех 3х функций делает это при выходе из фокуса.
Может как-то использовать событие "oninput"?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let formName = document.getElementById('form-name');
let formEmail = document.getElementById('form-email');
let formPhone = document.getElementById('form-phone');

formName.addEventListener('input', validate);
formEmail.addEventListener('input', validate);
formPhone.addEventListener('input', validate);

function validate() {
  let answerName = validation.isName(formName.value);
  let answerEmail = validation.isEmail(formEmail.value);
  let answerPhone = validation.isPhoneNumber(formPhone.value);
  
  if (answerName && answerEmail && answerPhone) {
    // Условие, которое выполняется, когда все поля true
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! Очень интересное решение, создать отдельно события и прослушать их в одной функции хм браво. Вы великолепны как всегда!